# Azure Arc - Windows Admin Center preview freezes on "gathering environment info"

Tags: azure, windows-admin-center

I have tried to run WAC from Arc on clean, fully updated, installs of both Windows Server 2022 and 2019. In both cases, I used the generated script from Arc on the Azure Portal with single server login. Once the server has the Arc agent successfully installed I restart the box, and install WAC from the Arc page in Azure. The agents appear to install and start correctly, however, when I attempt to Connect to the WAC service via the Azure Portal, the service hangs for one hour at "Gathering environment info" and then sends me back to the connect page without presenting any error states. The machines are VMs on VMware Workstation for testing purposes.

Is there something that I am missing (or was not made clear in the documentation) to get the service to function, or is there a known bug?